# Python Как взять первые тридцать объектов из массива

Tags: python, json, python-2.x

API запрос выводит данный код

```
    {
   "data": [
      {  
         "Phrase": (string),
         "GeoID": [
            (int)
            ...
         ],
         "SearchedWith": [
            {  
               "Phrase": (string),
               "Shows": (int)
            }
            ...
         ],
         "SearchedAlso": [
            {  
               "Phrase": (string),
               "Shows": (int)
            }
            ...
         ]
      }
      ...
   ]
}
```

Есть цикл который перебирает все объекты данного массива

```
    i=0
for x in responsedata['data']:

        for ph in responsedata['data'][i]['SearchedWith']:
            print '%s:%s' % (ph['Phrase'], ph['Shows'])
            b = str(ph['Phrase'].encode('utf8'))
            c = str(ph['Shows'])

            # записываем в файл каждую фразу, полученную от Яндекса
            f.write(b + ':' + c + '\n')
            if i == 30: continue
        if i == 30: continue
        i = i + 1
```

Он работает

```
       {  
           "Phrase": (string),
           "Shows": (int)
        }
```

Таких объектов в SearchWith более 300 штук, нужно взять только первые 30 объектов из SearchWidth, Пробовал цикл While пишет что это индекс списка через который меняется вывод объекта является строкой а не числом.

Answer (score 3):

Как-то так:

```
for x in responsedata['data'][:30]:
    for ph in x['SearchedWith']:
        print '%s:%s' % (ph['Phrase'], ph['Shows'])
        # ...
```

см. что такое [срезы](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/indeksy-i-srezy.html).

В принципе исходный вариант тоже будет рабочим (хотя и кривым), если заменить `continue` на `break`. см. [описание](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/cikly-for-i-while-operatory-break-i-continue-volshebnoe-slovo-else.html) оных операторов и циклов как таковых.